# How to set state of multiple properties in one event handler (React)

Tags: html, react.js, jsx

Pretty straight forwards really...I know that it's usually bad practice to repeat your code so I'm wondering how I could join handleAuthorChange() and handleContentChange() into one method. I guess it was hard for me to find a solution because I don't understand how I would know which part of the state I'm updating. I was thinking maybe embed a HTML id and check on the event target if IDs match but that seems pretty inefficient. Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddComment extends Component {
    state = {
        author: '',
        content: ''
    }

    handleAuthorChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            author: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleContentChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            content: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addComment(this.state);
        this.setState({
            author: '',
            content: ''
        });

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="add-form">
                <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit } className="card hoverable p-bottom">
                    <p className="p-top">ADD COMMENT</p>
                    <input onChange={ this.handleContentChange } value={this.state.content} type="text" placeholder="comment" />
                    <input id="name" onChange={ this.handleAuthorChange } value={this.state.author} type="text" placeholder="name" />
                    <input value="submit" type="submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AddComment;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it fine as it is, but if you really want to keep a single method, you can parametrize it by the name of the key to set:

```
handleChange = (keyName, e) => { this.setState({ [keyName]: e.target.value }); }
```

and call it like `handleChange('content', event)` or `handleChange('author', event)`.

Problem is, now, to call it properly when creating your components. You could write things like:

```
<input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange('content', e)} value={this.state.content} type="text" placeholder="comment" />
```

But this syntax creates a new function each time the component is rendered, potentially triggering child re-render as well. [React recommends](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) functions in the constructor instead:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddComment extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { author: '', content: '' };
        this.handleAuthorChange = this.handleChange.bind(this, 'author');
        this.handleContentChange = this.handleChange.bind(this, 'content');
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(keyName, e) {
        this.setState({ [keyName]: e.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addComment(this.state);
        this.setState({ author: '', content: '' });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="add-form">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="card hoverable p-bottom">
                    <p className="p-top">ADD COMMENT</p>
                    <input onChange={this.handleContentChange} value={this.state.content} type="text" placeholder="comment" />
                    <input id="name" onChange={this.handleAuthorChange} value={this.state.author} type="text" placeholder="name" />
                    <input value="submit" type="submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default AddComment;
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I didn't know about the bind() method - good to know!

Comment: Also, In my example, if I were to keep it how it is...should I be using a constructor function and using 'super(props)'??

Comment: @user3158670 since the arrow methods automatically binding `this` are still considered experimental, I prefer to explicitly `bind` my methods, thus I need a constructor. But your original code is clear enough without it.